# VBA matching and update existing and add new field into Next Empty Cell on next row

Tags: vba, excel, match, vlookup

I'm new here and I am trying to do a VBA Vlookup function.

My objectives is to VLookup Table1 from Sheet 1 to Table2 from Sheet2 using Column A and update column B and C if A is existing.

If A is not existing to add into Table1 next blank row with column B and C also included.

Please refer below image - expectation of Sheet1 with updated results.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Currently able to code only to update existing fields but not sure how to add fields that does not match into next blank row of Sheet1.

```
Sub getOpenExcel()

    '   Your daily report has a date in it's name
    '   to select an open workbook we must first know it's name
    '   AND - it must be already open
    '   Your examples are 2017-03-11-18875, 2017-03-12-18875, 2017-03-13-18875

    '   If the name is the current date then this would work to get the filename

    Dim fileName As String, monthNum As String, dayNum As String, wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    '   this adds a ZERO to the front of month numbers less than 10
    If Month(Date) < 10 Then
        monthNum = "0" & CStr(Month(Date))
    Else
        monthNum = CStr(Month(Date))
    End If


    '   You may or may not need this section
    '   it adds a ZERO to the front of day numbers less than 10
    If Day(Date) < 10 Then
        dayNum = "0" & CStr(Day(Date))
    Else
        dayNum = CStr(Day(Date))
    End If
    '   many cases the daily report will come from the previous day
    '   If your file has yesterday's date, then comment out the above code and
    'uncomment the following code
    '
    'If Day(DateAdd("d", -1, Date)) < 10 Then
    '    dayNum = "0" & Day(DateAdd("d", -1, Date))
    'Else
    '    dayNum = Day(DateAdd("d", -1, Date))
    'End If


    fileName = "GREENBILL_RECON_DETAILED_REPORT_" & CStr(Year(Date)) & monthNum & dayNum
    '   if today's date is 3/14/17 then "fileNem" = "2017-03-12-18875"

    '   If your daily report is an excel book, then we need to add the proper extension.
    '   It could be one of many, "xls", ".xlsx" , ".xlsm", etc....
    '   If your daily report is open - look at the top.  It should have the file name and extension.'
    '   Replace the below extension with the correct one.
    fileName = fileName & ".csv"
    '   Again, if today's date is 3/14/17 then "fileNem" =  "2017-03-12-18875.xlsx"


    '   This is where we set both workbooks to variables
    '
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    On Error GoTo notOpen
    Set wb2 = Workbooks(fileName)                ' This is your daily report
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("GREENBILL_RECON_DETAILED_REPORT")
    ws1.Activate
    '*************************************************************************************
    ' If successful this is the area where you put your code to copy and paste automatically '
    ' If you need this pasted to the first empty row at bottom of page then 'put code here to find the first empty row and use that varaible
    ' with range("a" & firstUnusedRow) intstead of A1 ...

    wb2.Activate
    Range("A1:Z500").Copy _
          Destination:=wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 'change A1 to A &
    firstUnusedRow
    '*************************************************************************************
    ' This is the clean up and exit code

    Set wb1 = Nothing
    Set wb2 = Nothing
    Exit Sub
notOpen:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set wb1 = Nothing
    MsgBox "The file " & fileName & " is not open"
    Exit Sub

End Sub

Sub Rectangle3_Click()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Dept_Row As Long                         ' To Change to Billing_Acc
    Dim Dept_Clm As Long                         ' To Change to Org_Seqno

    Table1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")              ' Input file name
    Table2 = Sheet2.Range("A1:B10")              ' Range of table

    Dept_Row = Sheet1.Range("B1").Row
    Dept_Clm = Sheet1.Range("B1").Column

    For Each cl In Table1
        Sheet1.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
        Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
    Next cl
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but well... you just described what you need to do and how you need to do it, so why don't you just do it...?

Comment: Hi @Rawrplus, I need to update the list daily and the a new worksheet is generated without the old fields. Hence I need this logic. I have created VBA for updating column B & C but I am unsure how could I add the logic into VBA to add fields that is not found in A into the next blank row for Sheet1. Thank you.

Comment: that's all fine and dandy. Still though, my main point was - the way it works here is you are expected to post your current efforts so far. Ideally in your case this means the code of your current efforts. This place is dedicated to help you out with your code, not to do the coding for you :)

Comment: @Rawrplus, thanks for explaining to me. I will copy the codes over.

Comment: Still unclear to me how the algorithm is supposed to work. I mean, I get that you basically want to fuse the two tables into a one big one, but it's not clear to me what is the main concept here. If i get it right, you are first looping through table one, if the value is however in table2, the table2 value gets posted instead and then you just add the extra values that are not included in both tables? **Please try to describe the calculation of your expected result in algorithm like fashion**

Comment: Also one more thing regarding the code, don't just dump your entire code here. Rather post the code that would only relate to the question directly. **Please check the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines!**

Comment: The first part of the code is getting the date in the right format for the filename - try `Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")` which will return _2018-06-26_ for todays date.  Not sure what the `18875` bit on the end is though.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook It was how the files are being generated by the IT department

Comment: @Rawrplus Yes, sorry for pasting everything over. And yes the concept of this is to check table 1 from table 2. If Column A field already exists, update Column B & C field. If Column A field does not exist, to add Column A field from table 2 to table 1.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is done iterating thru all the rows by matching column A of both sheets. If not found this will add a new line in sheet1.

```
Dim lngRow1, lngRow2 As Long
lngRow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lngRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim isFound As Boolean
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i, j As Long

lastRow = lngRow1
For i = 1 To lngRow2
    isFound = False
    For j = 1 To lngRow1
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j) Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & j)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & j)
            isFound = True
        End If
    Next j
    If Not isFound Then
        lastRow = lastRow + 1
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastRow) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & lastRow) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & lastRow) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i)
    End If
Next i
```

Code written considering the above example image. if number of columns are different than the example please modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Omg thanks Nagarajan. You are a life savior. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would it be possible to set any validations as if I click the button multiple times, "Fin" will be duplicated multiple times below each other.

And when I add additional rows fields to Sheet2, the fields will not be copied over to Sheet1.